# MEAN-stack mongoose, where do functions go?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

So I'm fairly new to the mean-stack and I'm using mean.js as a framework.

Using Yeoman I've made a new CRUD module called groups. In a group I want to be able to have an owner, the user who made the group, and a collection of members. According to the mongoose docs I gave the GroupSchema the following structure:

```
var GroupSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill Group name',
        trim: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    members: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Member'}]
});
```

Now, when a group is created the only member will be the owner. I've got the following app structure:

```
Project:
  - app (server side code)
    - controllers
    - models
    - routes
  - public (client side code)
    - modules
      - groups
        -controllers
```

Where do I put the method to add the current user to a certain group? My best guess is that the controller should take care of that, but is it the server or the client side controller?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't set it on the client or trust the client. Your server side create function should ignore `members` completely and just push the current user onto the members array.